# Flutter: Display two GridView one after another in a single page

Tags: flutter, gridview

I have two GridView data to be displayed in a single page one after another i.e. I want a single scrolling screen, when scrolling up after crossAxisCount: 1 finish, crossAxisCount: 2, should come behind it. When I use the following code, it divides the screen into two fixed parts the upper half displays the first GridView data and the lower half displays the second GridView data and both are scrollable separately. If I use body:SingleChildScrollView instead body:SafeArea the resulting output is a white screen (no data on screen) with error in console "Failed assertion: line 2009 pos 12: 'hasSize' The relevant error-causing widget was Scaffold". Please help me to solve this problem. Here is the complete program can be run individually on your system.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class GetUserData extends StatefulWidget {
  const GetUserData({super.key});

  @override
  State<GetUserData> createState() => _GetUserDataState();
}

class _GetUserDataState extends State<GetUserData> {
  Future<List> getUserData() async {
    String url = 'https://telugu-signaler.000webhostapp.com/get_user.php';
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: '');
    var allUserData = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    return allUserData;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Get User Data'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 8,
              child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                future: getUserData(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: GridView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true, //add this line
                        gridDelegate:
                            const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 1,
                          mainAxisExtent: 150.0,
                        ),

                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          String userFirstName =
                              snapshot.data![index]['user_first_name'];
                          String userLastName =
                              snapshot.data![index]['user_last_name'];

                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                                child: Text(
                                  'First Name: $userFirstName',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                                child: Text(
                                  'Last Name: $userLastName',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 8,
              child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                future: getUserData(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: GridView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true, //add this line
                        gridDelegate:
                            const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          mainAxisExtent: 150.0,
                        ),

                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          String userDistrict =
                              snapshot.data![index]['user_district'];
                          String userState =
                              snapshot.data![index]['user_state'];

                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.lightGreen,
                                child: Text(
                                  'District: $userDistrict',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.lightGreen,
                                child: Text(
                                  'State: $userState',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try these?

- First of all, wrap the Column widget with SingleChildScrollView.
- Later, remove all Expanded widgets.
- And add physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), to the GridView widget.